# get data after check exists one query laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I need to check if the data is exist and get data after that

Exam:

```php
Loc::fisrt()->user()->exists()->get(); // This is just an example, it's not true
```

->get after exists this i need

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide clarification about what you wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the data and check it afterwards.

```
$user = Luc::first()->user;
```

If `user()` is a `belongsTo`, `hasOne` or `morphOne` relationship:

```
if ($user !== null) { /* user exists */ }
```

If `user()` is a `belongsToMany`, `hasMany`, `hasManyThrough`, `morphMany`, `morphToMany` or `morphedByMany` relationship:

```
if ($user->isNotEmpty()) { /* user exists */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a perfect solution for what you need in Eloquent already. The [has](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method.

```
$results = Loc::has('user')->get();
```

The above results will only contain `Loc` records that have a `user` relation attached to them.